# Get attribute value of <li> from unordered list <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show ID value of "li" with attribute `aria-selected="true"` inside the span with class `categoryID`

My code looks like this:

```js
var category_Tree = $('#categorycontainer').find("[aria-selected='true']");
var selected_category = category_Tree.attr("id"); 

$('.categoryID').html(selected_category);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="categorycontainer">
   <ul>
      <li url="http://www.google.com" id="1" aria-selected="true">Google</li>
      <li url="http://www.yahoo.com" id="2" aria-selected="false">Yahoo</li>
      <li url="http://www.bing.com" id="3" aria-selected="false">Bing</li>
      <li url="http://www.facebook.com" id="4" aria-selected="false">Facebook</li>
      <li url="http://www.amazon.com" id="5" aria-selected="false">Amazon</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<span class="categoryID"><span>
```

But it is not working, any help please

Comment: testing the code you posted, it seems to be working well...

Comment: Your example works fine. Questions: **(1)** Where is this code in your page? **(2)** Is it wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: try `console.log(category_Tree)` maybe there is more than one element returned. if so you have to specialize your query like `.find("#categorycontainer [aria-selected='true']")` - well a bit more specialized since you dide that, but you get the point :D

Answer (score -2):

You can get all element that has attribute `aria-selected='true'` using **css attribute selector**. After selecting li element you get their id through id property.

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll('#categorycontainer>ul>li[aria-selected=true]');
let categoryID = document.querySelector('.categoryID');
let ids = '';
for(let i of li){
  ids+=(i.id+'\n');
}

categoryID.textContent = ids;
```

```html
<div id="categorycontainer">
   <ul>
      <li url="http://www.google.com" id="1" aria-selected="true">Google</li>
      <li url="http://www.yahoo.com" id="2" aria-selected="false">Yahoo</li>
      <li url="http://www.bing.com" id="3" aria-selected="true">Bing</li>
      <li url="http://www.facebook.com" id="4" aria-selected="false">Facebook</li>
      <li url="http://www.amazon.com" id="5" aria-selected="false">Amazon</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<span class="categoryID"><span>
```

Comment: You've simply re-written OP's code in a different way. It isn't a "solution" - you haven't told OP what was wrong with his/her example, nor why yours fixes that issue. (Hint: OP's code has nothing wrong with it, so there really isn't a valid answer until they supply us with more detail.)

Comment: @TylerRoper I think His problem was to add every element's id whose attr aria-selected is true. but OP's code was not working when there are more elements whose attribute value of aria-selected is true. You can check his code his code in codepen. And for jquery, he can use jquery selector '$' insetead of document.querySelector.

Answer (score -3):

First transforms the html to data in this case an array of objects and then it is easy to filter. From here on it is easier, try the following:

```js
const dataset = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul li')].map(li => ({ id: li.id, selected: li.getAttribute('aria-selected') }))
const data = dataset.find(data => data.selected === 'true')

document.querySelector('.categoryID').textContent = data.id;
```

```html
<div id="categorycontainer">
  <ul>
      <li url="http://www.google.com" id="1" aria-selected="true">Google</li>
      <li url="http://www.yahoo.com" id="2" aria-selected="false">Yahoo</li>
      <li url="http://www.bing.com" id="3" aria-selected="false">Bing</li>
      <li url="http://www.facebook.com" id="4" aria-selected="false">Facebook</li>
      <li url="http://www.amazon.com" id="5" aria-selected="false">Amazon</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<span class="categoryID"><span>
```

Comment: You've simply re-written OP's code in a different way. It isn't a "solution" - you haven't told OP what was wrong with his/her example, nor why yours fixes that issue. (Hint: OP's code has nothing wrong with it, so there really isn't a valid answer until they supply us with more detail.)

Comment: In my answer I try to emphasize that in this type of cases it is simpler and easier to work with data than manipulating the DOM. The example tries to highlight that. I think it is a valid answer